# Chebyshev's series for square-root of x over $x\geq 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, chebyshev-polynomials

I am looking for the derivation of Chebyshev's series expansion for $\sqrt{x}$ over $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$. I am little confused on how to go from $[-1,1]$ range of Chebyshev's polynomial range to $\mathbb{R}^{+}$.

Comment: As stated in the Wikipedia [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) article, the range is $\,[-1,1].\,$ It implies that the function to be approximated is bounded. Thus you can't use it for $\sqrt{x}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to map
$x \in (0, \infty)
$
to 
$y \in(-1, 1)$.

$\dfrac1{1+x}
$
maps
$(0, \infty)$
to
$(0, 1)
$
so
$\dfrac{2}{1+x}-1
=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}
$
maps
$(0, \infty)$
to
$(-1, 1)
$.

The inverse mapping for
$y =\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}
$
is
$y+xy = 1-x
$
or
$1-y = x(1+y)
$
or
$x = \dfrac{1-y}{1+y}
$.

Get the Chebychev series for
$\sqrt{\dfrac{1-y}{1+y}}
$
for
$-1 < y < 1
$
and then,
for any $x \in (0, \infty)$,
get the series for
$\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}
$.